# Some explanations on Date.now

Tags: javascript, date

Could someone explain to me what this returning number means? and how it is derived to that?

```
console.log(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

If I wanted to use the above formula to display the next 15minutes and not 24 hours? how would I alter it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns:

> the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

`24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` in milliseconds represents 24 hours<sup>*</sup>. So you basically get a timestamp 24 hours in the past from now. Notice that due to DST this doesn't necessarily compute a timestamp one day in the past. It's 24 hours in the past.

Also to get some meaningful output you should wrap resulting number in `Date`:

```
console.log(new Date(Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Finally `Date.now()` can be replaced with `new Date()` when using in arithmetic expression.

<sup>* - 24 (hours) times 60 (minutes in hour) times 60 (seconds in minute) times 1000 milliseconds in second</sup>.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you. So if I wanted to instead check past 15 minutes? or 10 minutes instead of 24 hours, how would I alter it?

Comment: @BaconJuice: should be obvious (?). 15 minutes is 15 * 60 seconds, which is 15 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds.